# Can world events be ended early?

Tags: terraria

I was playing Terraria and as soon I got into Hardmdode I got hit by a pirate invasion. The pirates killed me over and over again because I didn't have any hardmode gear. I tried quitting and rejoining the server but the event kept going. Is there anyway to stop the event instead of fighting all of the enemies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to skip any event (other than blood moon and solar eclipse using the enchanted sundial which you get from fishing crates) so you need to finish it. One way that could speed it up would be [hoiks](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hoik).